# NAV Bar Text overlaps one another when changing Display Size

Tags: html, css, navigation, nav

At 100% zoom, my webpage looks great, but when I start to zoom in, the texts start to shift together overlapping terribly, rather than staying at their place. I have tried making the position static, then it messes with the entire thing and then the nav bar stops sticking to the top. What am I doing wrong?

```css
header{
    background-image: url(banner1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-color: #FACABC;
    background-position: center;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    color: #FACABC;
    font-family: RedRock, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
    line-height: 5px;
}

.title{
    font-size: 500%;
}

h2{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: primer, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
    font-size: 200%;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #FACABC;
    color: #987b74;
}

#homelink{
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 2%;
    font-size: 135%;
    font-family: RedRock, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
    color: #FACABC;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
}

ion-icon{
    padding-left: 6em;
    font-size: 41px;
    color: #987b74;
}

ion-icon:hover{
    color: #FACABC;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

body{
    font-family: RedRock, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
    margin: 0;
}

.container{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    background: #FACABC;
    z-index:1;
}

/* Nav bar*/
    
nav{

    z-index: 9999;
}

.container nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 76px;
    
    
    font-size: 48px;
    padding-left: 7em; /* Centers "Home, About me, Socials, etc" text */
}

.container nav a{
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #987b74;
    padding-right: 100px;
}

.container nav ul{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.container nav ul li{
    width: 10%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    color: #987b74;
    font-size: 41px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    position: sticky;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
}

.container nav ul li:hover{
    color: #5E4C47;
}   

.container nav ul li ul.sub-nav {
    position: absolute;
    background: white; /* Background of drop down */
    width: 75%;
    height: 110px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14), -1px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
    top: 75px;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

.container nav ul li ul.sub-nav li{

    font-size: 31px;
    font-family: primer, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
    width: 75%;
}

.container nav ul li:hover ul.sub-nav{ /* Drop down menu visibility */
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 75%;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.container li{
    display: inline-block;
}

.container nav ul li ul.sub-nav a:hover{
    color: #5E4C47;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.container nav ul li ul.sub-nav a{
    padding: 0;
}

main h2{
    padding-right: 10em;
    padding-left: 10em;
}

main .learn-more{
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #FACABC;
  border: none;
  color: #987b74;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 275px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
font-family: primer, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
}

main .learn-more span{
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

main .learn-more span:after{
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

main .learn-more:hover span{
  padding-right: 25px;
}

main .learn-more:hover span:after{
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
} 

.video-trailer{
    background-image: radial-gradient(#f8f8f8, #FACABC, #f8f8f8);
}

main ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 0%;
}

main h1{
    font-size: 60px;
}

footer{
    text-align: center;
    color: #987b74;
}

.backgroundcolor{ /* To get that cream color background!*/
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

table {
  font-family: primer, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
  color: #987b74;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

table td, table th {
  padding: 8px;
}

table tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }

table tr:hover {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

table th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #987b74;
  font-size: 200%;
}

table td{
  border-top: 1px solid #987b74;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #987b74;
  border-right: 1px solid #987b74;
  text-align: center;
}

td:last-child{
    border-right: 0px;
}

.video-trailer h1{
    color: #987b74;
}
.video-trailer h2 a{
    color: #987b74;
}
.video-trailer h2 a:hover{
    color: #FACABC;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div id="wrapper">
    <title>HighItsKy</title>
    <link href="highitsky.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/redrock" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/primer" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">     

<body>
    <header>
        <a id="homelink" href="index.html">
            <h2 id="homelink">HighItsKy</h2>
        </a>
        <br><br><br><br>
        <span class="title"><h1>HighItsKy</h1></span>
        <h2>part time streamer, full time vibe</h2>
        <br><br>
        <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/highitsky/" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-twitch"></ion-icon></a>
        <a href="https://discord.gg/M2umXEhkNq" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-discord"></ion-icon></a>
        <a href="https://youtube.com/highitsky" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-youtube"></ion-icon></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/highitsky_/" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-instagram"></ion-icon></a>
        <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@highitsky" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-tiktok"></ion-icon></a>
        <a href="https://www.twitter.com/highitsky_/" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon></a>
        <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
        <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
        <br><br><br><br><br>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <a href="index.html">
                    <li>Home</li>
                </a>
                <li>About Me
                    <ul class="sub-nav">
                        <a href="AboutMe.html">
                            <li>ABOUT</li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="Cloves.html">
                            <li>CLOVES</li>
                        </a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Socials
                    <ul class="sub-nav">
                        <a href="Socials.html">
                            <li>SOCIALS</li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="Contact.html">
                            <li>CONTACT</li>
                        </a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <a href="Community.html">
                    <li>Community</li>
                </a>
                <a href="Partnerships.html">
                    <li>Partnerships</li>
                </a>
                <li>Support
                    <ul class="sub-nav">
                        <a href="Donate.html"><li>DONATE</li></a>
                        <a href="Merch.html"><li>MERCH</li></a>
                        <a href="Causes.html"><li>CAUSES</li></a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost you had a lot of margins and padding in your `li` and `a` related container styles. I removed those and added `white-space: nowrap;` inline on your "About Me" section. This causes the word not to break into two lines when resizing. I also threw in a couple of `media queries`. Feel free to change these as desired. However, the first one has to do with the `font-size` of the elements when the screen is being resized to `1000px` and it changes at that size. The other one changes your flex-direction from `row` to `column` at a certain size so it's more mobile-friendly.

Lastly, I added a class called `tabs` on your `<ul>`. I put a flex box on these components which will make them easier to style more responsively.

```css
header{
    background-image: url(banner1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-color: #FACABC;
    background-position: center;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    color: #FACABC;
    font-family: RedRock, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
    line-height: 5px;
}

.title{
    font-size: 500%;
}

h2{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: primer, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
    font-size: 200%;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #FACABC;
    color: #987b74;
}

#homelink{
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 2%;
    font-size: 135%;
    font-family: RedRock, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
    color: #FACABC;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
}

ion-icon{
    padding-left: 6em;
    font-size: 41px;
    color: #987b74;
}

ion-icon:hover{
    color: #FACABC;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

body{
    font-family: RedRock, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
    margin: 0;
}

.container{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    background: #FACABC;
    z-index:1;
}

/* Nav bar*/
    
nav{

    z-index: 9999;
}

.container nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 76px;
    
    
    font-size: 48px;
}

.container nav a{
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #987b74;
}

.container nav ul{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.container nav ul li{
    width: 10%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    color: #987b74;
    font-size: 41px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    position: sticky;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
}

.container nav ul li:hover{
    color: #5E4C47;
}   

.container nav ul li ul.sub-nav {
    position: absolute;
    background: white; /* Background of drop down */
    width: 75%;
    height: 110px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14), -1px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
    top: 75px;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

.container nav ul li ul.sub-nav li{

    font-size: 31px;
    font-family: primer, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
    width: 75%;
}

.container nav ul li:hover ul.sub-nav{ /* Drop down menu visibility */
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 75%;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.container li{
    display: inline-block;
}

.container nav ul li ul.sub-nav a:hover{
    color: #5E4C47;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.container nav ul li ul.sub-nav a{
    padding: 0;
}

main h2{
    padding-right: 10em;
    padding-left: 10em;
}

main .learn-more{
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #FACABC;
  border: none;
  color: #987b74;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 275px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
font-family: primer, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
}

main .learn-more span{
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

main .learn-more span:after{
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

main .learn-more:hover span{
  padding-right: 25px;
}

main .learn-more:hover span:after{
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
} 

.video-trailer{
    background-image: radial-gradient(#f8f8f8, #FACABC, #f8f8f8);
}

main ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 0%;
}

main h1{
    font-size: 60px;
}

footer{
    text-align: center;
    color: #987b74;
}

.backgroundcolor{ /* To get that cream color background!*/
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

table {
  font-family: primer, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
  color: #987b74;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

table td, table th {
  padding: 8px;
}

table tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }

table tr:hover {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

table th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #987b74;
  font-size: 200%;
}

table td{
  border-top: 1px solid #987b74;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #987b74;
  border-right: 1px solid #987b74;
  text-align: center;
}

td:last-child{
    border-right: 0px;
}

.video-trailer h1{
    color: #987b74;
}
.video-trailer h2 a{
    color: #987b74;
}
.video-trailer h2 a:hover{
    color: #FACABC;
}

/* additions */
.tabs {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .container nav ul li {
    font-size: 25px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 630px) {
  .tabs {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div id="wrapper">
    <title>HighItsKy</title>
    <link href="highitsky.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/redrock" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/primer" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">     

<body>
    <header>
        <a id="homelink" href="index.html">
            <h2 id="homelink">HighItsKy</h2>
        </a>
        <br><br><br><br>
        <span class="title"><h1>HighItsKy</h1></span>
        <h2>part time streamer, full time vibe</h2>
        <br><br>
        <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/highitsky/" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-twitch"></ion-icon></a>
        <a href="https://discord.gg/M2umXEhkNq" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-discord"></ion-icon></a>
        <a href="https://youtube.com/highitsky" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-youtube"></ion-icon></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/highitsky_/" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-instagram"></ion-icon></a>
        <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@highitsky" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-tiktok"></ion-icon></a>
        <a href="https://www.twitter.com/highitsky_/" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon></a>
        <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
        <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
        <br><br><br><br><br>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <nav>
            <ul class="tabs">
                <a href="index.html">
                    <li>Home</li>
                </a>
                <li style="white-space: nowrap;">About Me
                    <ul class="sub-nav">
                        <a href="AboutMe.html">
                            <li>ABOUT</li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="Cloves.html">
                            <li>CLOVES</li>
                        </a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Socials
                    <ul class="sub-nav">
                        <a href="Socials.html">
                            <li>SOCIALS</li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="Contact.html">
                            <li>CONTACT</li>
                        </a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <a href="Community.html">
                    <li>Community</li>
                </a>
                <a href="Partnerships.html">
                    <li>Partnerships</li>
                </a>
                <li>Support
                    <ul class="sub-nav">
                        <a href="Donate.html"><li>DONATE</li></a>
                        <a href="Merch.html"><li>MERCH</li></a>
                        <a href="Causes.html"><li>CAUSES</li></a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```